# How to trigger multibranch pipeline build on commit to branch?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a multibranch pipeline job, I have configured builds (basic linting) to scan across branches for a jenkins file.  I still have to perform this build manually however.  What is the property I can set to enable polling of GitHub or, even better, triggered on new commits.

In general, I'm trying to find a way to learn how all GUI fields map to keys I can use in the `properties();` method.  There is no way for me to translate between GUI form field and script key-value option.

```
node('master') {
    properties([
        [$class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '10']],
        [$class: 'BuildTriggerProperty???', strategy: 'Build when a change is pushed to GitHub???']
    ]);

...
}
```

Jenkins version 2.7

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to find a way to learn how all GUI fields map to keys I can use in the properties(); method.

If I got you correctly, the answer is:

1. Go to to your Pipeline project page
2. Find **Pipeline Syntax** link in the left-side menu and follow it
3. Find **Snippet Generator** link in the left-side menu and follow it
4. Select **properties: Set job properties** from **Sample Step** dropdown
5. Choose whatever you want and click **Generate Groovy**
6. Profit =)

Comment: this doesn't seem to always work.  i've found that they seem to be the same as what is exposed in the job xml.  `<jenkins_url>/job/<my_job>/api/xml`

Comment: When I first discovered this I really liked it. Sort of "makes up" for all of Jenkins' user-friendliness shortcomings. Until today when it generated the following code: `pipelineTriggers([<object of type com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.GitLabPushTrigger>])`.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work (anymore?)  as the only options are:

Build Triggers:

- Build periodically
- Build when another project is promoted
- Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built
- Monitor Docker Hub/Registry for image changes
- Periodically if not otherwise run
- Stash Pull Requests Builder

On a simple "pipeline" build, you can specify:

- Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket

But MultiBranch doesn't have this option.